# mwl-calendar does not render calendar - just outputs text

Tags: angularjs

I resolved it - it was a css issue

I am trying to integrate https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-bootstrap-calendar. There are no errors, but instead of rendering the calendar as per the demo page, it just prints out the days etc on the screen.

Here is my html:

```
div ng-controller="calendarCtrl">
    <mwl-calendar
        view="calendarView"
        current-day="calendarDay"
        events="events"
        view-title="calendarTitle"
        auto-open="true">
    </mwl-calendar>
</div>
```

and here is the controller:

```
app.controller('calendarCtrl', function($scope, $log, userData){

    var invoiceData = userData.getActivityData();
    $scope.calendarView = 'month';
    $scope.calendarDay = new Date();
    $scope.calendarTitle = "BirdsEyeView";
    if( invoiceData[0]){
      //$log.debug("in cal array:"+$scope.calendarDay);
    }
    else {
        $log.debug("No invoice data");
    }
    $scope.invoiceData = invoiceData;
    $scope.events = [
  {
    title: 'My event title', // The title of the event 
    type: 'info', // The type of the event (determines its color). Can be important, warning, info, inverse, success or special 
    startsAt: new Date(2015,6,10,1), // A javascript date object for when the event starts 
    endsAt: new Date(2015,6,10,15), // Optional - a javascript date object for when the event ends 
    editable: false, // If edit-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it editable. If set to false will also prevent the event from being dragged and dropped. 
    deletable: false, // If delete-event-html is set and this field is explicitly set to false then dont make it deleteable 
    incrementsBadgeTotal: true, //If set to false then will not count towards the badge total amount on the month and year view 
    recursOn: 'year' // If set the event will recur on the given period. Valid values are year or month 
  }
];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this was a CSS issue - the download from npm did not have the css. So did a manual download.